# Removing image from figure - python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, figure

I added an icon (png) to a figure. In a second moment I'd like to remove the icon from the figure while keeping the figure (and everything else I plotted on the figure) open. Any suggestion?
this is how I add the icon to the figure:

```
self.figure = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12), dpi=70)
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((30,30), (0, 0), rowspan=40, colspan=40)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, bottom=0.05, right=0.95, top=0.97, wspace=0.2, hspace=0.2)
#other lines here
icon = matplotlib.image.imread('image.png')
iconbox = matplotlib.offsetbox.OffsetImage(icon, zoom = 0.1)
ab = matplotlib.offsetbox.AnnotationBbox(iconbox, (x1,y1), frameon = False)
ax1.add_artist(ab)
```

I tried ab.remove() but the command doesn't get executed because the script hangs at plt.show(). If I set matplotlib.interactive(True) the command is executed but the window with the figure doesn't show up

Comment: the opposite of `add_artist(ab)` is `ab.remove()`

Comment: I tried that but but the command doesn't get executed because the script hangs at plt.show(). If I set matplotlib.interactive(True) the command is executed but the window with the figure doesn't show up

Comment: I added a self-contained, runnable example to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

To remove an object call its [`remove`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.artist.Artist.remove.html?highlight=remove#matplotlib.artist.Artist.remove) method. You need to [`redraw`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.FigureCanvasBase.draw_idle) to see the change.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
icon = matplotlib.image.imread(matplotlib.cbook.get_sample_data('Minduka_Present_Blue_Pack.png', asfileobj=True))
iconbox = matplotlib.offsetbox.OffsetImage(icon)
ab = matplotlib.offsetbox.AnnotationBbox(iconbox, (0.5,0.5), picker=True)
ax.add_artist(ab)
ax.set_title('Click on icon to remove it')

def onpick(event):
    event.artist.remove()
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

plt.show()
```

[image]